# On form submission, I want data from two different components angular

Tags: angular, forms, service

I am new in Angular and is building a form. On submission, I want some additional data from another component. How to achieve it? I know I can use a service but I can't achieve it. Any example will be highly grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @viewchild to get data from another component

try from below link

http://www.eduforbetterment.com/sharing-data-via-viewchild-in-angular/

Comment: No, viewchild will not work for sibling components, for that you have to use service.
For you I search document on service, hope this will help you to understand easily
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4